# Updating and fetching a Django model object atomically

Tags: django, django-models

I want a capability to update-and-read an object atomically. For example, something like a first() on top of update() below:

obj = MyModel.objects.filter(pk=100).update(counter=F('counter') + 1).first()

I know it is awkward construct. But just want to show my need.

For the record I have used class method like:

```
@classmethod
def update_counter(cls, job_id):
   with transaction.atomic():
       job = (cls.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=job_id))
       job.counter += 1
       job.save()
   return job
```

where I would call as below and get my updated obj.

my_obj = my_obj.update_counter()

But the question is, is there any other django model technique given such read back are common and likely used by multiple threads to conclude something based on, say, the final count.

Comment: what is wrong with your current class method? Why do you need this new method? It has not a sql direct translation, it needs two sql operations any way.

Comment: @daniherrera I agree. Yet just wondered whether there is any db level atomic mechanism to do the same for me without ceding control to python that requires a transaction.atomic. May be not. Currently, yes, the class method serves my purpose well. – SoundaR 7 hours ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging deeper I could not find any direct way of getting the object(s) that I am updating in an sql chained way. As Dani Herrera commented above the update and read have to be two sql queries. Only mechanism that helps me with that requirement is therefore the class method I had also included above. In fact, it helps me to add additional field updates in the same class method atomically in future.

For example, the method could very well be "def update_progress(job_id, final_desired_count)" where I can update more fields such as "self.progress_percentage = (self.counter / final_desired_count) * 100".

The class method approach may turn out to be a good investment for me.